# What sets of real numbers are definable in the language of real closed fields?

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, first-order-logic, real-numbers, descriptive-set-theory

The language of the first-order theory of real closed fields consists of the non-logical symbols $0$, $1$, $+$, $\cdot$, $<$, and $=$.  My question is, for what subsets $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ does there exist a formula $\phi(x)$ in the language of real closed fields such that $X=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\phi(x)\}$?

I’ve heard people say that the semi-algebraic sets, i.e. finite unions of singletons and intervals, are what’s definable in the language of real closed fields.  But I think they mean something slightly different than what I’m asking about.  Because there are uncountably many singletons and intervals, but only countably many formulas.

Comment: I mean, you can't define infinite fields on the reals at all, since they require infinite formulas.

Comment: What do you mean by define infinite fields?  I’m just asking what subsets of the set of real numbers are first-order definable.

Comment: I suppose it was meant that the singletons and interval endpoint all need to be algebraic numbers

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen At least that’s not part of the definition of semialgebraic set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set But yeah, it does seem plausible that the answer to my question would be semialgebraic sets with algebraic endpoints.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan In other words, we talk about semialgebraic sets *defined over the subring* $\Bbb Z$ (or equivalently, over $\Bbb Q$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct: With countably many formulas **without parameters**, only countably many subsets can be defined.

The definable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ in the language $\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{or}}:=\{0, 1, +, \cdot, <\}$ of ordered rings are unions of intervals (degenerated or otherwise) with algebraic endpoints, exactly as [commented above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398602/what-sets-of-real-numbers-are-definable-in-the-language-of-real-closed-fields#comment6991500_3398602) by Hagen von Eitzen.
A reference for this fact is Marker's [*Model Theory, An Introduction*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387987606), Sect. 3.3.

There, it is proved that real closed fields have quantifier elimination in $\mathcal{L}_{\mathrm{or}}$, and the result follows from this.

Comment: Does this statement hold true of arbitrary real closed fields or just $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Everything works for arbitrary real closed fields.